# Getting key with the highest value from object

Tags: javascript

I have a object like that one:

```
Object {a: 1, b: 2, undefined: 1}
```

How can I quickly pull the largest value identifier (here: `b`) from it? I tried converting it to array and then sorting, but it didn't work out, since it got sorted alphabetically (and it seems like a overkill to juggle data back and forth just for getting one value out of three).

Comment: do you want to get `2` or `b` as a result

Comment: I want to get `b` ;-)

Comment: see:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142884/fast-way-to-get-the-min-max-values-among-properties-of-object .. bonus answer:: you get min value as well along with max in this answer .. :)

Answer (score 196, accepted):

For example:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, undefined: 1};

Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b){ return obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b });
```

In **ES6**:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, undefined: 1};

Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b);
```

Comment: Thanks, but please note that there can be more items, like `c, d, e... x`.

Comment: this works for more items.. the reduce function is an iteration through the whole array ;)

Comment: Sorry for being a bother, but how can I also get a `2` besides `b`?

Comment: @CD.. if I use this in this case "var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2};" it return only c but I need b & c, means all keys with highest  values

Comment: @Dinesh, try: `var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2},
    keys = Object.keys(obj),
    largest = Math.max.apply(null, keys.map(x => obj[x]))
    result = keys.reduce((result, key) => { if (obj[key] === largest){ result.push(key); } return result; }, []);`

Comment: @CD when there are multiple keys with the same highest value, your solution returns the final key, how can I make this return the first key instead?

Comment: @FarisZacina I think Tomek meant `(a, b) => (a, b, c, d, e, f...)` instead of the object

Answer (score 39):

Using Underscore or Lo-Dash:

```
var maxKey = _.max(Object.keys(obj), function (o) { return obj[o]; });
```

With ES6 Arrow Functions:

```
var maxKey = _.max(Object.keys(obj), o => obj[o]);
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jt631Lcc/)

Comment: As of Lo-Dash 4.0.0 this should now be `var maxKey = _.maxBy(_.keys(obj), function (o) { return obj[o]; });`.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a suggestion in case you have many equal values and not only one maximum:

```
    const getMax = object => {
        return Object.keys(object).filter(x => {
             return object[x] == Math.max.apply(null, 
             Object.values(object));
       });
    };
```

This returns an array, with the keys for all of them with the maximum value, in case there are some that have equal values. 
For example: if

> const obj = {apples: 1, bananas: 1, pears: 1 }
>    //This will return ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears']

If on the other hand there is a maximum:

> const obj = {apples: 1, bananas: 2, pears: 1 }; //This will return ['bananas']
>   ---> To get the string out of the array: ['bananas'][0] //returns 'bananas'`

Comment: Hi, where should I put the object var exactly? When I console.log I get a "function getMax()"

Comment: ```object``` is the argument that the function above takes, the above is the ES6 syntax for defining functions, equivalent to: ```function getMax(object)``` , does that answer your question?

Answer (score 9):

```
{a: 1, b: 2, undefined: 1}
```

**The best work around I've seen is this**

```js
const chars = {a: 1, b: 2, undefined: 1}

//set maximum value to 0 and maxKey to an empty string
let max = 0;
let maxKey = "";

for(let char in chars){
  if(chars[char]> max){
    max = chars[char];
    maxKey= char
  }
}

console.log(maxKey)
```

Answer (score 8):

Supposing you've an `Object` like this:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, undefined: 1}
```

You can do this

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null,Object.keys(obj).map(function(x){ return obj[x] }));
console.log(Object.keys(obj).filter(function(x){ return obj[x] == max; })[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Very basic method. might be slow to process

```
var v = {a: 1, b: 2, undefined: 1};

function geth(o){
    var vals = [];    
    for(var i in o){
       vals.push(o[i]);
    }

    var max = Math.max.apply(null, vals);

     for(var i in o){
        if(o[i] == max){
            return i;
        }
    }
}

console.log(geth(v));
```

Answer (score 3):

Combination of some ideas from other answers. This will get all the keys with the highest value, but using the spread operator to get the maximum value and then filter array method:

```
const getMax = object => {
  let max = Math.max(...Object.values(object))
  return Object.keys(object).filter(key => object[key]==max)
}

let obj = {a: 12, b: 11, c: 12};
getMax(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return an array from an object with the keys for all duplicate properties with the (same or equal) highest value, try this:

```
const getMax = Object.keys(object)
   .filter(x => {
             return object[x] == Math.max.apply(null, 
             Object.values(object));
   })
var object = { orange: 3, blue: 3, green: 1}
console.log(getMax) // ['orange', 'blue']
```

Comment: This helps a lot for this scenario. Though, running this in the console does produce an error for me. The fix is to simply declare the object first so that the references resolve.

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = {a:1,b:2,undefined:3}
let maxValue = Object.entries(data).sort((x,y)=>y[1]-x[1])[0]
```

note: this is a very expensive process and would block the event loop if used with objects of large sizes(>=1000000). with large array slice the entries and call the above method recurrently using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getMaxRepeat(arr) {
  
  if (!arr.length) return;
  
  let str = arr[0].toString();
  let index = 0;
  let max = 0;
  let map = {};
  
  while (index < str.length) {
    if (index < arr.length) {
      str += arr[index];
    }
    
    if (map[str[index]]) {
      map[str[index]]++;
      
      if (map[str[index]] > max) {
        max = map[str[index]];
      }

    } else {
      map[str[index]] = 1;
    }

    index++;
  }
  
  Object.entries(map).map((item) => {
    if (item[1] !== max) {
      delete map[item[0]];
    }
  });
  
  return map;
}

const arr = [1, 66, 3, 4, 6, 78, 88, 9, 5];
console.log(getMaxRepeat(arr));
```