# Getting all minimal Values from dictionary javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a long dictionary with many entries `{y:10, au:41, w:41, m:11, u:21, t:1, d:1}`
What i need is to get all keys with the lowest value in a array. I found this ([Getting key with the highest value from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object)) but that doesn't work for multiple minimums(maximums)

and i need to use only core javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest and easiest is probably to get the objects keys as an array with `Object.keys`, and filter that array based on items having the lowest value.
One would need to find the lowest value first, then filter, here's one way to do that

```js
var obj    = {y:10, au:41, w:41, m:11, u:21, t:1, d:1};
var keys   = Object.keys(obj);
var lowest = Math.min.apply(null, keys.map(function(x) { return obj[x]} ));
var match  = keys.filter(function(y) { return obj[y] === lowest });

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' +JSON.stringify(match, null, 4)+ '</pre>';
```

Getting the keys, then creating a array of the values that is passed to `Math.min.apply` to get the  lowest value in the object.

Then it's just a matter of filtering the keys for whatever matches the lowest value in the object.

Here's another way using `sort`

```
var obj   = {y:10, au:41, w:41, m:11, u:21, t:1, d:1};
var keys  = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b) { return obj[a] - obj[b]; });
var match = keys.filter(function(x) { return obj[x] === obj[keys[0]]; });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var object = { y: 10, au: 41, w: 41, m: 11, u: 21, t: 1, d: 1 },
    result = function (o) {
        var keys = Object.keys(o);
        return keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
            if (o[k] < o[r[0]]) {
                return [k];
            }
            if (o[k] === o[r[0]]) {
                r.push(k);
            }
            return r;
        }, [keys.shift()]);
    }(object);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This is the most efficient (if anyone cares), since it's one-pass.