# JS: What is the cleanest way of finding the highest value from an object and return its key?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate through some characters and using a hashmap to keep track of characters seen already.  I now have an object with characters and how many times they are encountered. 
I know I can get the values by doing:

`Object.value(myObj).sort((a,b) => {return b - a})[0]`
 but I don't know how to use that highest value I have to relate back to the key it belongs to.

Comment: Can you show your object in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key with the highest value from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object)

Answer (score 2):

```
let maxValue;
let maxKey;

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObj)) {

  if (value > maxValue) {
    maxValue = value;
    maxKey = key;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is much more efficient than grabbing all of the keys and then sorting them, as it takes only 1 iteration and uses less RAM as it doesn’t make extra arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *key* of the highest value, sort the *keys*:

```
Object.keys(myObj).sort((a,b) => {return myObj[b] - myObj[a]})[0]
```

EDIT: This is the minimal modification of your code; though a straight search as per Evert's answer will be faster, if you don't need the other elements.

Comment: I feel the operator should be greater than instead of minus

Comment: @vdj4y: First of all, I left the operator alone - I was going for minimal modification of OP's code. Secondly, the operator is correct if the sorted values are numeric, as the callback for `sort` needs to return an integer, not a boolean. For any other kind of comparison (e.g. strings), this is indeed not correct - but then OP's code wouldn't have worked either. In such a case, a conditional should be made so it can return `-1`, `0` or `1`; not just plain `true` or `false`.

Comment: yeah, it return integer, 1 or 0 or -1. I could be wrong, but from what I know. it's like "if(a < b) return 1 else if (a ==b) return 0 else return -1".

Comment: @vdj4y: The spec just says the three cases are negative, zero and positive; with `31 - 47` you get a negative, which is good enough, no need to transform it into `-1`. With strings you can't do that with just subtraction, and we return `-1` for convention and simplicity, even though `-16` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

It will take the highest value and compare the keys. After that it will return the key associated with the highest value.

```js
var a={w:1,e:2,g:5};
var value=Object.values(a).sort((a,b) => {return b - a})[0];
console.log(Object.keys(a).filter((e)=>a[e]==value?true:false)[0])
```

Comment: Do note that this sorts the array repeatedly for each element.