# How can I get the largest number value along with the username from this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-5

Im trying to get the user & value with the highest number from this array but have had no luck in my searches. I'm starting to wonder if my array is poorly written.

```
{
  "radtech2": 1,
  "conorlarkin4": 25,
  "jdon2001": 15,
  "nobel_veo": 101,
  "frapoden": 1,
  "duckyboy17": 31,
  "faeded": 30,
  "jimbob20001": 17,
  "leb0wski": 15,
  "3cavalry": 2,
  "hardoak22": 25,
  "deep_slide": 10000,
  "sillywil": 7
}
```

Comment: To start with - this is not an array - it is an object.

Comment: I did not downvote you - and I also did not provide an alternative answer because I agree with the comment from @CertainPerformance - in which you have not attempted to show any workings or attempted solution. Simply giving an answer to the question does not address  that issue nor does it inspire you to try something and ask for help. SO is not a code writing service - it is a code assistance service. That presumes the presence of code.

Comment: Thanks, i'm not an avid stackoverflow user so it was not my intention to "do it wrong". I've tried several things to solve my problem already & did not know I had to post them here in order to have the honour of getting an answer.

Comment: The first comment should have been a guide on what to do to meet the requirements of a good post.

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like? The title says you want the value *and* username, but the question text makes it sound like you just want the username.

Comment: Also, probably a duplicate of [Getting key with the highest value from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object)

Comment: @herohtar Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const users = {
  "radtech2": 1,
  "conorlarkin4": 25,
  "jdon2001": 15,
  "nobel_veo": 101,
  "frapoden": 1,
  "duckyboy17": 31,
  "faeded": 30,
  "jimbob20001": 17,
  "leb0wski": 15,
  "3cavalry": 2,
  "hardoak22": 25,
  "deep_slide": 10000,
  "sillywil": 7
};

const highestUser = users => Object.keys(users).reduce(
  (highest, current) => highest.val > users[current] ? highest : { user: current, val: users[current] },
  { user: undefined, val: -Infinity }
).user;

console.log(highestUser(users));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keys()` and `entries()` methods to search your JSON object. Save largest value into e.g. `const largest` and then find out which key belongs to this value.

Answer (score -1):

Let me try to squeeze it into a one-liner approach using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const users = {
  "radtech2": 1,
  "conorlarkin4": 25,
  "jdon2001": 15,
  "nobel_veo": 101,
  "frapoden": 1,
  "duckyboy17": 31,
  "faeded": 30,
  "jimbob20001": 17,
  "leb0wski": 15,
  "3cavalry": 2,
  "hardoak22": 25,
  "deep_slide": 10000,
  "sillywil": 7
};


const res = Object.keys(users).reduce((a, b) => users[a] > users[b] ? a : b);

console.log(res);
```

How the above code works is that I get the array of keys from the `users` object, and I use reduce to get the highest possible value and return the corresponding property from the array obtained from Object.keys().

Answer (score -1):

What you show in your question is an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array); however, it does need to be turned into an array in order to work with it.

You can do that with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which will return an array of all the key/value pairs in the object.

Then you can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to extract the one with the largest value.

```js
const data = {
  "radtech2": 1,
  "conorlarkin4": 25,
  "jdon2001": 15,
  "nobel_veo": 101,
  "frapoden": 1,
  "duckyboy17": 31,
  "faeded": 30,
  "jimbob20001": 17,
  "leb0wski": 15,
  "3cavalry": 2,
  "hardoak22": 25,
  "deep_slide": 10000,
  "sillywil": 7
}

let winner = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, b) => (a[1] > b[1]) ? a : b)

console.log(winner)
```