# Get variable name for math.max

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, math

I'm trying to get the variable with the `winner`. I ask for the highest number but how get I get the according `player / variable name`:

```
var A = 0;
var B = 0;
var C = 0;
var D = 0;
var E = 0;
var F = 0;
var G = 0;
var H = 0;


$('.answer').on('click', function (evt) {

     const types = $(this).data("typ").split(" "); // split on space.
     const active = $(this).is('.active');
     
     types.forEach(typ => { 
        if (active) {
          window[typ]--
    } else {
         window[typ]++
    }
  })
    console.log(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});


$('.fin').on('click', function (evt) {
    
    var players = ['playerA': A, 'playerB': B,'playerC': C,'playerD': D,'playerE': E,'playerF': F,'playerG': G, 'playerH': H];
    
    var winner = Math.max.apply(null, players );
    
    alert(winner, 'wins');
    
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use separate variables. Use an array.

Comment: Then after you get the max you can find its index in the array.

Comment: You can't use `key: value` notation in an array, only in an object.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what you mean. Can I still use the answer-function with the array only? Do you mind showing it (newbie ;) if it is no hassle for you. Thanks either way.

Comment: Ah I know what you mean with key: value now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an object to store your values with play names (i.e. `{}` rather than an array which uses `[]`).

You can then use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object) to get the highest value.

---

Working Demo:

```js
var A = 0;
var B = 1;
var C = 2;
var D = 3;
var E = 9;
var F = 5;
var G = 6;
var H = 7;


$('.fin').on('click', function (evt) {
     
    var players = {'playerA': A, 'playerB': B,'playerC': C,'playerD': D,'playerE': E,'playerF': F,'playerG': G, 'playerH': H};
    
    var winner = Object.keys(players).reduce(function(a, b){ return players[a] > players[b] ? a : b });

    
    alert(winner, 'wins');
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="fin">Fin</button>
```