# How to dispatch calculation to relevant function according to input's type?

Tags: typescript, function

When writing a function in *TypeScript*, is there a way to let the function infer what to do according to the input's type?

For example, let's say that I have a function that calculates the maximum value.

- In **scenario A**, the input is a numeric array (i.e., `type: number[]`), and I want it to return the max value. So I could do:

  ```js
  const calcMaxArr = (arr: number[]): number => {
    return Math.max(...arr) // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106546/6105259
  }
  ```
- In **scenario B** I also want to calculate the max value, but this time my input data is an object, and I want to return the *key* that corresponds to the largest *value*. In this case I could do:

  ```js
  const calcMaxObj = (obj: Record<string, number>): string => {
     return Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376421/6105259
  }
  ```

While these two functions (`calcMaxArr()` & `calcMaxObj()`) work perfectly well, I wonder whether I could unify them somehow under one function `calcMax()`. That is, I wonder whether `calcMax()` can infer, from the input's type, whether to defer/dispatch the calculation to `calcMaxArr()` or to `calcMaxObj()`.

```
If type: number[] -> calcMaxArr()
If type: Record<string, number> -> calcMaxObj()
```

Is there a built-in feature in typescript for such kind of a task?

---

EDIT

---

I ran across [this tweet](https://twitter.com/kearneymw/status/1497293614698971136?s=20&t=NEQgGbZVWEvSe5XvabQlnA) that demonstrates a similar procedure but in *python*. For those who know *python*, this makes a useful analogy in my opinion.

---

EDIT 2

---

I've now learned that what I am asking about actually has a name: My `calcMax()` is a [*generic function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_function), and one built-in implementation of such generic functions is [seen in Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#Defining_generic_functions_and_methods), for example.

Comment: The [@arrows/multimethod](https://caderek.github.io/arrows/packages/multimethod/#defining-types) module seems to hit the spot. Unfortunately, it's a [1-person project](https://github.com/caderek/arrows/graphs/contributors), and therefore far from being a built-in language feature as I hoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you...

```ts
const calcMax = (inputs: number[] | Record<string, number>): number | string => {
  if (Array.isArray(inputs)) {
    return calcMaxArr(inputs);
  }
  return calcMaxObj(inputs);
}

const calcMaxArr = (arr: number[]): number => {
  return Math.max(...arr) // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106546/6105259
}

const calcMaxObj = (obj: Record<string, number>): string => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376421/6105259
}
```

---

### ***Illustration***

```js
"use strict";
const calcMax = (inputs) => {
  if (Array.isArray(inputs)) {
    return calcMaxArr(inputs);
  }
  return calcMaxObj(inputs);
};

const calcMaxArr = (arr) => {
  return Math.max(...arr); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106546/6105259
};

const calcMaxObj = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376421/6105259
};

console.log(calcMax([10, 8, 12, 3]));
console.log(calcMax({
  "10": 10,
  "8": 8,
  "12": 12,
  "3": 3
}));
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: Thanks. So you suggest that if I have, say, 10 different input types, then I should just do an `if-else` flow inside `calcMax()`?

Comment: Well, if we take input which is a union then we will have to employ type discrimination on that union in order to select a suitable function that can handle that special type of input. However, using an `if-else` is only one of many ways and is simple in demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

**Long story short**: what you want to achieve is not possible. TypeScript gets compiled to JavaScript and all data about types is not available in the runtime, it's effectively removed. So you have to implement runtime checks yourself (solution by @Nalin Ranjan is just one way to do it), TypeScript can't do that for you.

However I can suggest one improvement to the solution provided by @Nalin Ranjan - use overloads. The provided solution has a big problem - the return type is always a union type, in other words:

```
let k = calcMax({twelve: 12, ten: 10});
console.log(k.length); // error even though we expect string
```

This would fail because type of `k` is `string | number` and `.length` property is only available on strings.

To fix it you should, like I mentioned, use overloads, like this:

```
function calcMax(arr: number[]): number;
function calcMax(obj: Record<string, number>): string;

function calcMax(arg: any): any {
    if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
        return calcMaxArr(arg);
    }
    return calcMaxObj(arg);
}
```

Now the example above will work properly. In this particular scenario it might look verbose, but let's imagine you have another function, like:

```
const calcMaxSet = (set: Set<number>): number => { 
  return 0; // implementation doesn't matter
}
```

Then you just have to look at signatures. Since both `calcMaxSet` and `calcMaxArr` return the same type you can add it to the existing overload, same would be true if `calcMaxObj` actually returned `number` (but then you wouldn't even need an overload):

```
function calcMax(arr: number[] | Set<number>): number;
function calcMax(obj: Record<string, number>): string;

function calcMax(arg: any): any {
    if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
        return calcMaxArr(arg);
    } else if (arg instanceof Set) { // runtime check
        return calcMaxSet(arg);
    }
    return calcMaxObj(arg);
}

let k = calcMax(new Set([1,2,3]));
k.toFixed(); // k is a number so this is legal
```

Comment: Helpful indeed!!!. Just that I haven't made myself comfortable with `overloads` yet in typescript! :-). But nice, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Is function overload what you need?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

```
const calcMaxArr = (arr: number[]): number => {
  return Math.max(...arr) // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106546/6105259
}

const calcMaxObj = (obj: Record<string, number>): string => {
   return Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376421/6105259
}

function calcMax(arr: number[]): number;
function calcMax(obj: Record<string, number>): string;
function calcMax(input: number[] | Record<string, number>) {
  if(Array.isArray(input)) {
    return calcMaxArr(input);
  }
  else {
    return calcMaxObj(input);
  }
}
```