# Get Max Key in Key-Value Pair in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please consider these Key-Value Pairs:

```
var dict_Numbers = {"96": "0",
                    "97": "1",
                    "98": "2",
                    "99": "1",
                    "100": "4",
                    "101": "0"}
```

I would like to get the highest value -  in this example it would be 101.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

---

**Update 1:**

I use this code: [Fast way to get the min/max values among properties of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142884/fast-way-to-get-the-min-max-values-among-properties-of-object) and [Getting key with the highest value from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object)

but both return Max Value from string comparator

Comment: With 4k rep you should know to write a [mcve] showing what you have tried. It is really not difficult to find examples here - Math.max and Object.keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key with the highest value from object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object) except that you've to use `parseInt` to convert the string to an integer.

Comment: @ArunKumar No That code compare values not keys

Comment: Can't you figure out how to compare keys instead of values from the answer I linked? See @mplungjan's answer. He has exactly done that.

Comment: look at this [example]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

You can iterate over the properties of the object and check for its value.

```js
var dict_Numbers = {
  "96": "0",
  "97": "1",
  "98": "2",
  "99": "3",
  "100": "4",
  "101": "5"
};

var max = 0;

for (var property in dict_Numbers) {
  max = (max < parseFloat(property)) ? parseFloat(property) : max;
}

console.log(max);
```

Comment: Seriously @Arian, that is the answer you went with? At least add the radix to the parseInt or you will have fun with 08 and 09

Comment: @mplungjan , dont yo think providing a default value is overkill, by default radix is 10 for parseInt() . May be i am wrong but it looks straightforward overkill but i do like sinisake's answer though

Comment: Right - so they fixed that. It used to give surprises with the invalid octal values 08 and 09

Comment: yeah but that will affect if try to parseInt a digit i.e. parseInt(015) which results 13 but with strings i.e. parseInt("015") it will not matter.

Comment: @Arian - why change to parseFloat? Will there be decimals in your "keys" ?

Answer (score 14):

Nice example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
var dict_Numbers = {"96": "0",
                    "97": "1",
                    "98": "2",
                    "99": "3",
                    "100": "4",
                    "101": "5"}
                    
                    
function getMax(obj) {
  return Math.max.apply(null,Object.keys(obj));
}
console.log(getMax(dict_Numbers));
```

Comment: Like I thought. I took the duplicate suggestion instead in my answer :)

Comment: [5 years later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41358362/295783): `const max = Math.max(...Object.keys(dict_Numbers))`

Answer (score 9):

Applying to the keys the easily found [Getting key with the highest value from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object) paying attention to the strings

```js
const dict_Numbers = {
    "96": "0",
    "97": "1",
    "08": "8", // just to make sure
    "09": "9", // just to make sure
    "98": "2",
    "99": "3",
    "100": "4",
    "101": "5"
  },
  max = Object.keys(dict_Numbers)
  .reduce((a, b) => +a > +b ? +a : +b)
console.log(max)
```

But as I commented on the question, there is a neater way using Math.max on the Object.keys

Now even more elegant using spread

```js
const dict_Numbers = {
    "96": "0",
    "97": "1",
    "08": "8", // just to make sure
    "09": "9", // just to make sure
    "98": "2",
    "99": "3",
    "100": "4",
    "101": "5"
  },
  max = Math.max(...Object.keys(dict_Numbers))
console.log(max)
```

Comment: Sinisake's answer is good, but seems to only work if the keys are numeric, yours works with all keys.

Comment: @AlexCollette see TWO modern versions

Answer (score 4):

```js
var dict_Numbers = {"96": "0",
                    "97": "1",
                    "98": "2",
                    "99": "3",
                    "100": "4",
                    "101": "5"}

console.log(Math.max(...Object.keys(dict_Numbers)));
```

Note that this code uses ES6 features.

Comment: Cool but the `return Math.max.apply(null,Object.keys(obj));` is by far easier on the eye and brain

Comment: @mplungjan Actually, I think it is the other way around :)

Comment: I just removed the explicit `parseInt` because `Math.max` already does it. But in my opinion, reading the spread operator is easier than `.bind` anyway.

Comment: Using a transpiler should be standard practice by now :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dict_Numbers = {
    "96": "0",
    "97": "1",
    "98": "2",
    "99": "3",
    "100": "4",
    "101": "5"
  },
  key,
  intKey,
  maxKey = 0;

for (key in dict_Numbers) {
  intKey = parseInt(key);
  if (intKey > maxKey) {
    maxKey = intKey;
  }
}
console.log(maxKey);
```