# Get min value from a nested json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have json object of which I would like to get the min price. Below is the response.

```
[
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 217,
      "available": true
    }
  },
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 302,
      "available": true,
    }
  },
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 427,
      "available": true,
    }
  }
]
```

I have tried a solution from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142884/fast-way-to-get-the-min-max-values-among-properties-of-object) but it won't work in case.

```
  var arr = Object.keys( response ).map(function ( key ) { return response[key]; });
  var min = Math.min.apply( null, arr );
```

Please help

Comment: what is the `response` object?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal the json I pasted above is the response

Comment: At first you need to convert your json to js array using JSON.parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

native JS solution:

```
var t =[ { "room": { "price": 217, "available": true } }, { "room": { "price": 302, "available": true, } }, { "room": { "price": 427, "available": true, } } ]
var min = t.map(function(el){return el.room.price}).reduce(function(el){return Math.min(el)});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe0dcoym/)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```js
let response = [
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 217,
      "available": true
    }
  },
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 302,
      "available": true,
    }
  },
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 427,
      "available": true,
    }
  }
];
let values  = response.map(function(v) {
  return v.room.price;
});
var min = Math.min.apply( null, values );
console.log(min)
```

using ES2015 you can also make it in one line:

```
var min = Math.min.apply( null, response.map((v) => v.room.price));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have array not object so you can't use `Object.keys()`. You can also use spread syntax like this.

```js
var data = [{
  "room": {
    "price": 217,
    "available": true
  }
}, {
  "room": {
    "price": 302,
    "available": true,
  }
}, {
  "room": {
    "price": 427,
    "available": true,
  }
}]

var min = Math.min(...data.map(e => e.room.price))
console.log(min)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.protype.reduce()`

```js
var rooms = [{
    "room": {
      "price": 217,
      "available": true
    }
  },
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 302,
      "available": true,
    }
  },
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 427,
      "available": true,
    }
  }
];
console.log(rooms.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.price > curr.price ? curr : prev).room.price);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var response = [
            {
                "room": {
                    "price": 217,
                    "available": true
                }
            },
            {
                "room": {
                    "price": 302,
                    "available": true,
                }
            },
            {
                "room": {
                    "price": 427,
                    "available": true,
                }
            }
        ];

        debugger;
        if (response && response.length > 0) 
        {
            var min = response[0].room.price;

            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)           
                if (response[i].room.price < min)
                    min = response[i].room.price;

            console.log(min);
        }
```

Comment: You should perhaps explain your answer, rather than just post code.

Answer (score 0):

lbrutty code is a bit wrong and function will always return first element. So there is a little fix.

```
var t = [ { "room": { "price": 300, "available": true } }, { "room": { "price": 102, "available": true, } }, { "room": { "price": 427, "available": true, } } ];
var min = t.map(function(el){return el.room.price}).reduce(function(prevEl, el){return Math.min(prevEl, el)});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xe0dcoym/17/