# How can I add value in object at first number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a value at first number of an object, but it's not adding at first number, How can I do this?

```js
  let obj = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, '3': 33, '4': 44};
  const addNewValue = Object.assign({a: 1}, obj);
  console.log(addNewValue);
```

Output should be as given below:-

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "3": 33,
  "4": 44,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

But getting as given below:-

```
{
  "3": 33,
  "4": 44,
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your desired outcome is, can you please [edit] the post with what you want as a result?

Comment: @Samathingamajig & mplungjan I updated my question.

Comment: Add and sort....

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: @mplungjan: Sort based on what?

Comment: You can't really sort the keys of on object since you can't depend on the order to stay the same. That's not the point of objects.  If you care about the order, then use an array instead.  Using an array of strings or even an array of objects might be what you want.

Comment: If it's about `order`, you should prefer an `Array` instead. The whole point of `Object` notation is, it's order insignificant.

Comment: @ChrisBarr you CAN rely on the order since ES6 but only if you keep the traversal order

Comment: @mplungjan cool, ok I wasn't aware! That's a good feature, but at the same time it kind of feels wrong since it seems like either an array would be more appropriate, or maybe code should be restructured if it depends on the order of object keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JS object doesn't retain property insertion order with numbers, but `Map` does.

You could use a proxy to emulate an object-like map:

```js
const Obj = new Proxy(Object, {
  apply(_, __, args){
    return new Obj(...args);
  },
  construct(_, args){
    const obj = Reflect.construct(...arguments);
    const map = new Map;
    
    for(const arg of args){
      for(const key in arg){
       map.set(key, arg[key]);
      }
    }
    
    return new Proxy(obj, {
      getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_, prop) {
        return { configurable: true, enumerable: true, value: map.get(prop) };
      },
      ownKeys(){
         return [...map.keys()];
      },
      get(_, prop){
        if(prop === Symbol.iterator){
          return map.keys.bind(map);
        }
        if(prop in obj){
          return obj[prop];
        }
        return map.get(prop);
      },
      set(_, prop, value){
        map.set(prop, value);
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

});

const obj = Obj({b: 1, c: 2}, {1: 3, 2: 4});

const obj2 = Object.assign(Obj({a: 1}), obj);

console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj2.__proto__.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see below you cannot retain the order because you have numeric key mixed into this.

If the keys started with alphabetic characters you could, since ES6 rely on order if you keep the [traversal order](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html)

The code below shows how the order is already wrong as soon as we try to get the keys in any way

I posted this as dupe, but it was not. It does however explain why your object is not able to keep the order you gave it

[Sort a JavaScript object by key or value; ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319092/sort-a-javascript-object-by-key-or-value-es6)

```js
let obj = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, '3': 33, '4': 44};
const entryToAdd = ["a",1];

let entries = Object.entries(obj);
let orgKeys = Object.keys(obj);

orgKeys.unshift(entryToAdd[0]);
entries.unshift(entryToAdd);

const addNewValue = orgKeys.reduce((newObj, key) => {
    newObj[key] = obj[key] || (key === entryToAdd[0] ? entryToAdd[1] : undefined);
    return newObj;
}, {});

console.log(addNewValue); // NOT what you want but that is what you will get regardless
```