How is property order determined when using a spread operator on a JS object
I am using the spread operator and with the below code get expected results as far as element order in the resulting object
const morning = {
    breakfast: "oatmeal",
    lunch: "Peanut butter and jelly"
}

const dinner = "mac and cheese";

const backPackingMeals = {
    ...morning, 
    dinner
};

console.log(backPackingMeals);

//output:
/*{
    breakfast: 'oatmeal',
    lunch: 'Peanut butter and jelly',
    dinner: 'mac and cheese'
  }*/

The above is expected, it outputs the properties in the order they were added.
In the below though the output order is unexpected:
const backPackingMeals = {
    ...morning, 
    ...dinner
};

//result
/*{
  '0': 'm',
  '1': 'a',
  '2': 'c',
  '3': ' ',
  '4': 'a',
  '5': 'n',
  '6': 'd',
  '7': ' ',
  '8': 'c',
  '9': 'h',
  '10': 'e',
  '11': 'e',
  '12': 's',
  '13': 'e',
  breakfast: 'oatmeal',
  lunch: 'Peanut butter and jelly'
}*/


Not asking why dinner is broken into an array of letters but why that array prints before the 'breakfast' and 'lunch' properties

natural numbers go first as props in an object, due supporting of array-like objects (Array is actually an object with natural numbers being as props). If you want to retain order of number props, you could look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899978/how-can-i-add-value-in-object-at-first-number-in-javascript/76900289#76900289

there is no rules on order, in any browser or configuration

Well there are rules, but they're not under the programmer's control and in general it is a terrible design idea to rely on property ordering.
