# How to find the max value of an object?

Tags: javascript

Here is our object:

```
let obj = {a: 1, b: 3, c:10}
```

How can we return `c` as it contains maximum value?
there are simple solutions for arrays but I wonder how this one cloud be implemented

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way to get the min/max values among properties of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142884/fast-way-to-get-the-min-max-values-among-properties-of-object)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the `Object.entries` of the object, where the accumulator contains the entry of the greatest value so far, then access the `[0]`th value of the entry:

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 3, c:10};

const maxProp = Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((bestEntry, thisEntry) => thisEntry[1] > bestEntry[1] ? thisEntry : bestEntry)
  [0];
console.log(maxProp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` to the key|value pairs, and then use `Array.reduce()` to find the pair with the maximum value. At the end extract the key from the pair.

```js
const getMaxKey = o => Object.entries(o)
  .reduce((r, e) => e[1] > r[1] ? e : r)[0]

const obj = {a: 1, b: 3, c:10}

const result = getMaxKey(obj)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding adding another potential solution:

1. Find the max value
2. The result is its index

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 3, c:10}
max = Math.max(...Object.values(obj))
maxIndex = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === max)
console.log(maxIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findTheHighest(obj){

let highestNum = 0; //sets highestNum to 0

let winningKey = ""; //sets winningKey to a blank string

for(let key in obj){    //for in loop iterates through the keys of the // object that is passed in as an argument
   if(obj[key] > highestNum){ //acesses each key value through bracket //notation and compares it against the highestNum variable and the matching
```

//key essentially setting the highest value and its respective key

```
        highestNum = obj[key];
        winningKey = key;
    }
 }   
return highestNum //or switch return to winning key if you want the key //instead of value
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).