# Return Max Value from JS Object

Tags: javascript

I am looking for the most efficient way to retrieve the max value from the following object (outputted by dev console on Google) - knowing that the maximum value is 1002 but knowing it can dynamically change:

```
[Red: 1002, Orange: 24, Blue: 301, Pink: 106]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: i see no array ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the min/max element of an Array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: That isn't a valid array in your question. Is it supposed to be an object? Do you need the name of the color or just the number?

Comment: best would be do an array of objects

Comment: although that's no array, this should answer your question [Fast way to get the min/max values among properties of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142884/fast-way-to-get-the-min-max-values-among-properties-of-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be an Object, not an Array. `const max = Math.max(...Object.values(yourObject))` will do it.